# How can I redirect the STDOUT to STDIN in a C program

Tags: io-redirection, c

Lets say I want to write a C program that executes the same command as :  `ls -l | wc -l`

The following is an attempt :

```
int main(){
    int fd;
    char *buffer[] = {"ls", "-l", (char *) NULL};
    char *buffer1[] = {"wc", "-l",(char *) NULL};
    if(fork() == 0){
        // I make the STDOUT_FILENO and fd equivalent
        if((fd = dup(STDOUT_FILENO)) == -1){
            perror("error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        close(fd);
        if(fork() == 0)
            execvp(buffer[0], buffer);
        // then I make fd and STDIN_FILENO equivalent in order to put the output of the previous command
        // as the input of the second command
        if(dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO) == -1){
            perror("error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        execvp(buffer1[0], buffer1);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

But it just runs `ls -l` without feeding its output to `wc -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create a pipe between your two processes. (This is also what happens when you use `|` on the command line.)

There are a lot of examples how to do that, for instance [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-demonstrate-fork-and-pipe/).

Basically you create the pipe with a call to `pipe()`, and then each process closes one end of the pipe.